# Manipulating a float to unsigned into and back

Tags: c

I am currently working in C with a microcontroller and in order to transmit a reading over Bluetooth I have to send it as a uint8. The reading is currently in the form of a float. I've been trying to think of how to do this and then be able to convert it back to a float on the reciever end but have no ideas. I'm limited because I can't utilize a custom structure or anything because it has to be in a uint8 to transmit.

Any suggestions?

I have tried a couple things but none have gotten very far so I don't have much to show for it

Comment: You *do* know that the `float` value is stored in memory as a series of bytes? And that you can simply send those bytes one after another?

Comment: With that said, there's no guarantee that the floating-point formats of the sender and receiver is the same, or that the byte order is the same. So better use some other format to transmit the data, like for example a string?

Comment: Even with a more straightforward `int`, you'd have to account for possible endianness differences between sender and receiver.

Comment: Converting a float to a string is a rather complex operation. [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) is a rather common implementation and is probably used both sides, but you could have to track size (32 or 64 bits) and endianness questions between sender and receiver. Apart from that, it should be easy to transmit the *representations* as byte values...

Comment: When you say "a uint8", do you mean a single uint8 or a series of (say, 4) uint8?

Comment: Where did the reading come from? I don't think I've ever seen a sensor give a floating point value, so I suspect that someone created an unnecessary problem by converting the sensor's original data to floating point for no sane reason.

Comment: @Brandan There are cases where sensor input need to be put through processing which is best carried out using floating point arithmetic so it is not unheard of to have a (processed) sensor reading in a float.

Answer (score 1):

Any type in C can be traversed using character pointers and on all sensible compilers, `uint8_t` is a character type. For example:

```c
const uint8_t* ptr = (const uint8_t*)&some_var;
for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(some_var); i++)
{
  send_byte(ptr[i]);
}
```

Keep in mind however that your CPU endianess might not match network endianess, in which case you need to swap the byte order before sending.

Comment: @Lundin *"old schoo type-generic programming"*... What do you mean by that? Is there a modern school approach?

Comment: @Zakk Here's an illustration https://godbolt.org/z/8EsefreEn. I apologize if the code is a bit cryptic... But basically old school type-generic programming revolved around void pointers and passing along sizes and sometimes also enums corresponding to the type. Then in addition to that, pass along callbacks. (Think bsearch/qsort.) In modern C programming we can do compile-time type checks and decide what function to use based on that, branch free and everything. The modern version also don't have to call a callback over and over which is very inefficient.